# Antialiasing troubles

Tags: c++, directx, antialiasing

When full-scene antialiasing is enabled, I have some troubles when rendering to texture.

Here's an image of what is hapenning (rendered image has some edges).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLFLT.png

When AA is off - nothing of this happening, and all goes ok.

Why might I experience these troubles, and what is the correct way to render to texture while AA is on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to make sure your game is capable to run full scene anti-aliasing (thats is to assume you have a ready graphics card for the job). The way to do that is by doing this:

```
/*
* The code below assumes that pD3D is a valid pointer 
*   to a IDirect3D9 interface.
*/

if( SUCCEEDED(pD3D->CheckDeviceMultiSampleType( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, 
                    D3DDEVTYPE_HAL , D3DFMT_R8G8B8, FALSE, 
                    D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES, NULL ) ) )
// Full-scene antialiasing is supported. Enable it here.
```

If the device supports it then all you have to do is set up the parameters for multi-sampling:

```
/*
* The example below assumes that pD3D is a valid pointer 
* to a IDirect3D9 interface, d3dDevice is a pointer to a 
* IDirect3DDevice9 interface, and hWnd is a valid handle
* to a window.
*/

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETER d3dPP
ZeroMemory( &d3dPP, sizeof( d3dPP ) );
d3dPP.Windowed        = FALSE
d3dPP.SwapEffect      = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dPP.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES;
pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
                    D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                    &d3dpp, &d3dDevice)
```

Hope this helps!